# how do i change font size for 3.5 and 4 inch devices?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

i have set up constraints for `Compact Any`, `Compact Regular`, `Any Any` yet no matter what i do im unable to design my UI to cater to 3.5 and 4 inches

Notice how on the 3.4 and 4 inch device, net, goal and inv gets cut off[image]. what i really want to do is shrink the font size so that it can fit properly. how do i go about doing so?

Comment: `UILabel` has an `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property.  Set that to true and set a `minimumFontScale` and it will scale automatically

Comment: has no effect, my 3 labels still get cut off on device and storyboard preview